# Vector implementation of product of column vectors in python

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication

Is there any vector implementation of multiplying columns in 2D-data to generate a single column which contains the product of all column values in python?
For example
[[1,2,3],[2,1,4],[1,7,3],[4,1,1]]
to
[6, 8, 21, 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `np.multiply` or `np.prod`

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,1,4],[1,7,3],[4,1,1]])
np.multiply.reduce(a, axis=1)
```

OR

```
np.prod(a, axis=1)
```

---

```
array([ 6,  8, 21,  4])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both of them work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try `product` from pandas

```python
L = [[1,2,3],[2,1,4],[1,7,3],[4,1,1]]
pd.DataFrame(L).product(axis=1).to_list()
# [6, 8, 21, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of using reduce from functools. This function "reduce" a list applying an operation in an accumulative way. The operation is going to be the product, implemented as a lambda, which is always more pythonic.

```
from functools import reduce
x = [[1,2,3],[2,1,4],[1,7,3],[4,1,1]]
y = [reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, element) for element in x] #=[6, 8, 21, 4]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.